# Android MySQL PHP syntax error unexpected echo

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

**UPDATE: I've edited the question to be more specific:**

**so the problem was a hidden character i could only see openning the file on my webhost editor, and then it was missing '' on the $id**

So, i've already looked everywhere for an answer, and i simply can't find it, so was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/ to learn how to make CRUD operations connecting my app with MySQL server, and i got stuck on the part to get a single entry from table.

It gives me a **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/u728774671/public_html/db/getpost.php on line 28"** and i can't figure out why, my code is exactly as the one in the tutorial, except i changed name of table and variables.

what am i missing? am i doing something wrong or is it the tutorial code?

here is the code:

```
<?php 
//Getting the requested id
$id = $_GET['id'];

//Importing database
require_once('dbconnect.php');

//Creating sql query with where clause to get an specific employee
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$id'";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//pushing result to an array 
$result = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
array_push($result,array(
"id"=>$row['id'],
"titulo"=>$row['titulo'],
"usuario"=>$row['usuario'],
"endereco"=>$row['endereco'],
"post"=>$row['post'],
"imagem"=>$row['imagem']
 ));

//displaying in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is the line where the error is:

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

and this is the code from the tutorial:

```
 <?php 

 //Getting the requested id
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 //Importing database
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Creating sql query with where clause to get an specific employee
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id=$id";

 //getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 //pushing result to an array 
 $result = array();
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
 array_push($result,array(
 "id"=>$row['id'],
 "name"=>$row['name'],
 "desg"=>$row['designation'],
 "salary"=>$row['salary']
 ));
 
 //displaying in json format 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not currently on my pc, so I cant test your code, but i think you are getting a wrong json or something, could you `print_r` the `json_encode`

Comment: oh my god, you won't believe it, there was a hidden random character that i could only see by openning the file on my host editor"now i'm getting a new error: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u728774671/public_html/db/getpost.php on line 17**, to which i'm already searching for an answer

Comment: That error is saying that the resulting `mysqli_query` has an error, try to parse that mysqli and see if it has any error on sql query, look here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: yep, i got it already, now i'm having problems with JSON, it's returning html code, which is giving an excpetion, i tried substring to look for the issue but it just goes on from <html> to <head> to an entire html page, guess i'll just close this one and make another question for the JSON Exception, i'm searching for answers but can't really find why

Comment: Yes, create a new one